# Creating a table with data frames as rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I am using R to analyze some data that changes over time. Data is in csv format. It has only 2 columns (v1, v2). After the calculations are completed, I format them as dataframe. 
Each csv file read in, is a different test subject and I would like to export the results as a single csv file with the subject name as column 1. I have been naming each data frame after each subject, so is there an easy way to combine all the data frames into one table. I've been searching for a solution, but most of what I find is how to convert a table into a data frame, not the other way around. Or is there a better way to do this?

```
So, I currently have 3 data frames (Bob,Jake,Ray)
        v1  v2  v3
Bob     5   9   6
        v1  v2  v3
Jake    6   5   4
        v1  v2  v3      
Ray     3   2   5

But, I want to do this and then export as a .csv
        v1  v2  v3
Bob     5   9   6
Jake    6   5   4
Ray     3   2   5
```

Comment: Please make your example fully reproducible http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `rbind(Bob, Jake, Ray)` ...?

Comment: I agree with RHertel's comment. I recommend you take a look to the [Quick-R tutorial](http://statmethods.net/), specifically the [Data Management section](http://statmethods.net/management)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this and depending on how small or large this problem is a different solution might work. One option is to create a list and do an rbind

```
# get the names of data frames in environment. You can type it out too.
dfs <- ls()[sapply(ls(),function(x) class(get(x))[1] == "data.frame")]
# Create a list with all the data frames
li <- lapply(dfs,get)
names(li) <- dfs
# Combine them into a single data frame which can then be written to a csv file
dat <- do.call(rbind,li)
```